# Is there any way to do operations within predicate parameters?

Tags: prolog

Something like this:

```
increment(X, X2 is X + 1).
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
no.
```

well, unless having a wrapper predicate for `increment/3` that will perform the operation and then call the real `increment/3` is considered valid.

edit: lets assume that you want to write a wrapper for `foo(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)` so that you can pass an expression as a second argument. The wrapper would be:

```
efoo(Arg1, Expr, Arg3):-
    Arg2 is Expr,
    foo(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)
```

in case you want to do this a lot, you might want to abstract that behaviour:

```
eval_call(Predicate, Expressions):-
    maplist(evaluate, Expression, Args),
    call(Predicate,Args).

evaluate(Expr, Arg):-
    Arg is Expr.
```

Comment: Example, if you'd be so kind?

Answer (score 1):

there is [succ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=succ/2)/2 that has the semantic you require and a bit more

```
?- succ(3,X).
X = 4.

?- succ(X,7).
X = 6.
```

The title of the question seems requiring something more general, and as @thanosQR already pointed out, that syntax needs some change.

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard idiom is doing it separately, e.g.:

```
X2 is X + 1, increment(X,X2).
```